# change the default value of an integer column

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table

I have created a table with below schema

```
CREATE TABLE `userdetails` (
`uid` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`userName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`pwd` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
 KEY `userName` (`userName`),
 CONSTRAINT `userdetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userName`) REFERENCES `user`     (`uname`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now I want to remove default value for `uid` column.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter your table

```
ALTER TABLE `userdetails` CHANGE `uid` `uid` INT(5) NOT NULL;
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd080/1)

Also its better if you define it as `AUTO_INCREMENT` so every row will have a unique no.

```
ALTER TABLE `userdetails` CHANGE `uid` `uid` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ALTER TABLE` like this

```
   ALTER TABLE `userdetails` CHANGE `uid` `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL;
```